# Rename Git repository in Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

Is it possible to rename a Git repository in Google Cloud Source Repositories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According with the [API](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos), you can't. You only have create and delete for a repo, no update.

The best way is to create a new repo and then to delete the current one.